# Error when attempting to view a CRM Workflow - Error generating UiData

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

When attempting to view a Workflow in CRM I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #3C0AAE93
Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #3C0AAE93</Message>
  <Timestamp>2013-07-26T01:19:35.7786421Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147200969</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Error generating UiData</Message>
    <Timestamp>2013-07-26T01:19:35.7786421Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Has anyone come across this error before? I tried deleting running versions of the workflow with no success.

Comment: Side note to the above: It appears the offending Workflow (Process) has added itself to a MANAGED solution. Does anyone know how this is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart IIS and AsyncService and try again.

Someone else on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f528a1e-e2ec-4bd5-a0f7-e649f59f61c5/cannot-deactivate-workflow) had the problem and it turned out to be a custom workflow step causing the problem:

> So it looks like the problem was it had a custom workflow step that
>   was referencing a plugin that got moved/unregistered. I re-registered
>   the plugin and was able to deactivate the workflow.

Regarding it adding itself to a managed solution: Possibly something to do with dependencies when the managed solution was created. It should not be able to add itself in after a managed solution is created.

Comment: I can't restart the IIS or Async Service because its CRM Online unfortunately. :-(

Comment: this helped in my case

Answer (score 1):

This issue seemed to resolve itself.

We can only presume that it was something to do with the current upgrade of CRM Online (from Windows Live authentication to Office 365).

So unfortunately if anyone has this issue I cannot provide an answer. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the error by

1. Create an action with a custom workflow activity step and an input parameter of type EntityReference
2. Add the action to another workflow

Upon adding, I get

Error generating UiData for workflow
System.ArgumentException: Expected non-empty Guid.
Parameter name: user

Other behaviour: the entity drop-down for the action is empty in the workflow step where it is added. It should have global or whatever entity the action is targeting. Changing the action's input parameter type from EntityReference to a simple type resolves the error, as does removing the custom workflow activity step. Something seems like it was implemented incorrectly with "complex" input/output parameters such as EntityReference and EntityCollection. There are issues with them appearing in Web API as well, at least until v9. See https://butenko.pro/2016/09/23/action-not-available-webapi/

Answer (score 0):

In my case workflow was successfully opened in other browser (not IE). In IE it continued to display that error message.

Also the reason of this error may be in a child workflow, that could be converted to workflow template. If so you should to revert that template to workflow.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue was caused by custom workflow activities which were deployed to disk.  Some of the DLLs were missing, so apparently the system could not properly display the workflow definition.

I also began seeing this error when saving customizations and importing solutions.  The solution would fail with 'Dependencies Calculation', saying it 'failed to load assembly'.